# Bind line series to the additional Y-axis in radchart telerik

Tags: telerik, radchart

Im having radchart showing the 2 bar series and 2 line series.Bar series is showing according to the left side y axis and line series is not binding according to the right side additional y axis.right axis which line series has to bind but only one of them is binding and other is not showing it binding to the left Y-axis.

Please can anybody provide me any solution is much a appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
AxisY axisY = new AxisY();
axisY.AxisName = "AxisY1";
axisY.Title = "";
axisY.IsZeroBased = true;
axisY.DefaultLabelFormat = "#VAL{P0}";
SellInproductChart.DefaultView.ChartArea.AdditionalYAxes.Add(axisY);

AxisY axisY1 = new AxisY();
axisY1.AxisName = "AxisY2";
axisY1.Title = "";
axisY1.IsZeroBased = true;
axisY1.DefaultLabelFormat = "#VAL{P0}";

SellInproductChart.DefaultView.ChartArea.AdditionalYAxes.Add(axisY1);

objSeriesMapping1.SeriesDefinition.AxisName = "AxisY1";
objSeriesMapping2.SeriesDefinition.AxisName = "AxisY2";
```